# iTextsharp : reduce spacing between the characters in extracted text from pdf reader

Tags: c#, itext

I found more spacing between the characters happening from the extracted text from pdf reader. I don't want to use `"trim"`,`"replace"` functionality from the extracted text.

Suggest me how to avoid spacing between the character

I have tried ITextExtractionStrategy, but it didnt work

***I don't want to trim or replace comments from the extracted text***

```
StringBuilder pdfContent = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)

 {

ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                    pdfContent.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its));

  }

reader.Close();
                string strPdfContent = Convert.ToString(pdfContent);
```

================

## Extracted text:

> I n sp e c t i o n l o t : 123456789 M a t e r i a l 0 8 1 6 0 1 1 2 0
>   0 1 L B L D T U B E L I A T F L U A / B & R S V I V D B a t c h : 8 7
>   6 8 4 Z V e n d o r B a t c h : E x p i r y d a t e : 2 0 2 0 - 0 8 -
>   3 1 I n sp e c t i o n T y p e :  G o o d s R e c e i p t f r o m P r
>   o d u c t i o n

===============

## Expected text:

```
Inspection lot: 123456789
Material 07568681001 OBID CAR COBAS LIAT FLU A/B Batch: 87684Z
Vendor Batch: Expiry date: 2020-08-31
Inspection Type: Goods Receipt from Production
```

Comment: There is something special about your pdf - probably the lines are printed multiple times (e.g. once with only the descriptions, once with quantities and prices) and each time instead of the left out details spaces are printed, so at each position there is a space printed in addition to the actually desired character. Or probably the font in question claims the characters have width 0 (while the glyph actually is wider) and to forward the text insertion point to the next sensible position a space is added or a gap is added. Both kinds of documents have been dealt with here in questions.

Comment: For further analysis, therefore, please share an example pdf.